# Short story where some people discover their universe was within a piece of bacon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

About 40 years ago, I read a short story about some people who get on a spaceship to save their planet.

They keep going deeper and deeper into the universe and eventually go through a barrier. They find themselves in a basement with a vagrant man and realize that they have just burst out of a piece of bacon that the vagrant is just about to eat.

Comment: Any chance this was in an anthology? If so, would you happen to remember what other stories were featured, or what the cover looked like? Or if it was published in a magazine/newspaper, which ones did you use to read back then?

Comment: How painfully mundane. Wouldn't it be easier to list all the stories where the universe isn't bacon-based?

Comment: Jenayah, it was in a collection of stories in a sci-fi magazine. This was back in the former Yugoslavia, and the stories in the magazine tended to be from other countries, translated into Serbo-Croatian.

Comment: There was a bacon-themed science fiction anthology called the baconthology. Perhaps this was one of them? https://web.archive.org/web/20130512004444/http://www.baconpza.com/index.html

Comment: My husband, whose question this really is, now says that it may have been a sandwich or a sausage -- and maybe it was mistranslated, anyway. But definitely a food item.

Comment: Not a vegan story then?